# No se resolver este problema de estadística en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, estadística

El enunciado de mi pregunta es el siguiente

Introduzca el siguiente código en la consola de Spyder:

```
`"x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
  s=str(201529063);
  y=[0,5.8,10.3,(float(s)-2e8)/1e5, float(s[0]+ s[4:])/1e4,30+float(s[-1]),43.2]"`
```

Dados los 7 puntos (x,y), ¿cuál es la pendiente de la regresión lineal que pasa por el origen y predice los valores de "y" a partir de los valores de "x"?
Usa la búsqueda estocástica para dar con la pendiente de la linea que pasa por el origen y que minimiza la suma de las distancias ortogonales de los 7 puntos (x,y) a esa linea. ¿Cuál es la pendiente? Recibirás un punto por cada dígito correcto (hasta 5), por ello, no debes redondear el resultado. Utiliza los 7 valores de "x" e "y" creados en la pregunta anterior.

Aquí dejo lo que llevo de código:

```
from scipy.odr import Model, Data, ODR
from scipy.stats import linregress
import numpy as np


a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
s=str(idnum);
b=[0,5.8,10.3,(float(s)-2e8)/1e5,float(s[0]+ 
s[4:])/1e4,30+float(s[-1]),43.2]

x=np.array(a)
y=np.array(b)

def orthoregress(x, y):
   linreg = linregress(x, y)
   mod = Model(f)
   dat = Data(x, y)
   od = ODR(dat, mod, beta0=linreg[0:2])
   out = od.run()
return list(out.beta) + [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
def f(p, x):
   return (p[0] * x) + p[1]
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value,std_err=linregress(x,y)
print(slope)
```

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Hola Adriceb! Debes poner el código que has intentado y el problema específico que tienes, esto parece más como "Me han mandado un ejercicio, resolvedmelo vosotros".

Comment: @RubialesAlberto perdona si esa ha sido la impresión, aquí dejo lo que llevo hasta ahora de código.